# How to transform soap response to xml using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

am trying to transform soap response to xml using xslt but am getting only empty output.
Please any one help me.

**MY Soap response is**

```
<Envelope 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Body 
xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<OTA_HotelAvailRS TransactionIdentifier="12345" EchoToken="12345" Target="Test" TimeStamp="2008-03-18T10:46:53.393" Version="6.001">
<HotelImages>
<ImagePath>http://reznextlive.blob.core.windows.net/custcode-106/63710.jpg</ImagePath>
<ImagePath>http://reznextlive.blob.core.windows.net/custcode-106/63711.jpg</ImagePath>
<ImagePath>http://reznextlive.blob.core.windows.net/custcode-106/63712.jpg</ImagePath>
</HotelImages>
</OTA_HotelAvailRS>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

**My XSLT IS**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<images>
<xsl:value-of select="Envelope/Body/OTA_HotelAvailRS/HotelImages/ImagePath"/>
</images>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My output is like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<images xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

Comment: What is the output that you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet was close but at the `<Body>` tag there is an `xmlns` default namespace declaration that applies to that node and all of the children. It looks like you might have tried that because the `soap` prefix was declared in your stylesheet. Unfortunately the soap namespace in your stylesheet was incorrect; there should be no trailing `/`. Namespaces are compared lexically not semantically so the two are not equivalent.

Here is a sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<images>
  <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/soap:Body/soap:OTA_HotelAvailRS/soap:HotelImages/soap:ImagePath">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />,
  </xsl:for-each>
</images>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output you would get in your stylesheet would be the first image only. I added a `xsl:for-each` here as a sample.

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi env xsd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/env:Body/env:OTA_HotelAvailRS/env:HotelImages/env:ImagePath">
      <images>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
      </images>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You have to specify the namespace to which the node belongs in source xml, within xslt to access that node in xslt